# Scroline A Grid with objects in it on A Scene in AndEngine

Tags: android, andengine

I want to show a scrollable grid with objects in it on a scene.
What I want to do is I have a running scene and user clicks a rid button say Select Shapes.
When user clicks a grid is opened with 100 colors in it which means user must scroll to see and select the colors.
What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a [link](http://www.andengine.org/forums/tutorials/menu-scroll-example-t5740.html) to thread in the AndEngine Forum about Menu Scroll Example.
Just change menu items to your 100 colors and make them smaller.

Hope this help.